# undeclared identifier, object vector

Tags: c++, vector, undeclared-identifier

I am getting an error and I don't know how to fix it. I checked everything and maybe I overlooked something, but I am not able to find the problem.

Errors:

> ```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: Aquarium, Configuration: Release x64 ------
> 1>  Fish.cpp
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(21): error C2065: 'Fish': undeclared identifier
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(21): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(21): error C2976: 'std::vector': too few template arguments
> 1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(682): note: see declaration of 'std::vector'
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(24): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Fish'
> 1>  LooseCalculationClass.cpp
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(21): error C2065: 'Fish': undeclared identifier
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(21): error C2059: syntax error: '>'
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(21): error C2976: 'std::vector': too few template arguments
> 1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\vector(682): note: see declaration of 'std::vector'
> 1>c:\users\lloyd17\dropbox\aquarium project\aquarium\aquarium\EntityControl.h(24): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'Fish'
> 1>LooseCalculationClass.cpp(7): warning C4551: function call missing argument list
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

**Fish.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "EntityControl.h"
class Fish
{

private:
    //location of the fish
    unsigned int _xLocation = 0, _yLocation = 0, _zLocation = 0;
    //name of fish
    std::string nameOfFish;
    unsigned int speed;
public:
    //constructor
    Fish(std::string name, unsigned int fishSpeed)
    {
        nameOfFish = name;
        speed = fishSpeed;

    }   

    //getters
    int getX() const;
    int getY() const;
    int getZ() const;
    std::string getName() const;
    void changeX(unsigned int x);
    void changeY(unsigned int y);
    void changeZ(unsigned int z);

    void move();



    ~Fish();
};
```

**Fish.cpp**

```
#include "Fish.h"


int Fish::getX() const
{
    return _xLocation;
}

int Fish::getY() const
{
    return _yLocation;
}

int Fish::getZ() const
{
    return _zLocation;
}

std::string Fish::getName() const
{
    return nameOfFish;
}

void Fish::changeX(unsigned int x)
{
    _xLocation = x;
}

void Fish::changeY(unsigned int y)
{
    _yLocation = y;
}

void Fish::changeZ(unsigned int z)
{
    _zLocation = z;
}

void Fish::move()
{
    EntityControl entity;
    unsigned int x = rand() % entity.getXContainer();
    unsigned int y = rand() % entity.getYContainer();
    unsigned int z = rand() % entity.getZContainer();


}


Fish::~Fish()
{
}
```

**Aquarium.cpp(Main)**

```
using namespace std;
#include "EntityControl.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "LooseCalculationClass.h"
#include <thread>
#include "Fish.h"



int main() {
    /*Not using new in object definitions so I don't have to delete them afterwards since pointers don't stay in memory*/
    bool running = true;
    //defining my objects for functions
    EntityControl entity;
    LooseCalculationClass calc;
    vector<Fish*> fishVector;
    Fish a("Lloyd", 200);
    fishVector.push_back(&a);
    std::thread t1(&EntityControl::movementController, entity, &fishVector);
    //std::thread t2(&LooseCalculationClass::userInput, calc);
    //t2.detach();
    t1.detach();


    //main gameloop, prints out the results for every fish, waits a bit and then refreshes the screen
        while(running){
            for (auto Fish_ptr : fishVector) {
                calc.printOutXYZ(*Fish_ptr);
                Sleep(500000);
                system("pause");
                //system("cls");

            }
    }
     return 0;
}
```

**EntityControl.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Fish.h"
#include <random>
#include <array> 
#include <Windows.h>

class EntityControl
{
private:    
/*Didn't make a separate object because I only 
needed the x,y,z of the fish container although it is against the rules of object oriented programming*/
    const unsigned int _xContainer = 20;
    const unsigned int _yContainer = 60;
    const unsigned int _zContainer = 40;
public:
    /*grabs the location of a vector of fish pointers, then takes the 
    vector and accesses every object threw it's data location with dereferencing.
    (Controls the movement of the fish and prevents collision)*/
    void movementController(std::vector<Fish*> *fishInputVector);//thread!!

    //ACHTUNG! fishInput is the fish to check the surrounding of, changing this might bring up unexpected errors
    bool CheckCollision(Fish* fishInput , Fish* fishInput2);

    int getXContainer() const;
    int getYContainer() const;
    int getZContainer() const;

    ~EntityControl();
};
```

**EntityControl.cpp**

```
#include "EntityControl.h"

    /*if the container was much larger,
    then multiple threads would be a better solution*/ 
void EntityControl::movementController(std::vector<Fish*> * fishInputVector)
{
    while (true) {


        for (auto fish_ptr : *fishInputVector) {
        }
    }
}

bool EntityControl::CheckCollision(Fish * fishInput, Fish * fishInput2)
{
    //collision true/false
    bool collision = false;

    //collision detectors
    bool xCollision = false;
    bool yCollision = false;
    bool zCollision = false;

    //fishInput
    unsigned int xOriginal = fishInput->getX();
    unsigned int yOriginal = fishInput->getY();
    unsigned int zOriginal = fishInput->getZ();

    //fishInput2
    unsigned int xEntity = fishInput2->getX();
    unsigned int yEntity = fishInput2->getY();
    unsigned int zEntity = fishInput2->getZ();

    //directions, (triggerBox)
    if (xOriginal - 1 == xEntity || xOriginal + 1 == xEntity || xOriginal == xEntity) { xCollision = true; }
    if (yOriginal - 1 == yEntity || yOriginal + 1 == yEntity || yOriginal == yEntity) { yCollision = true; }
    if (zOriginal - 1 == zEntity || zOriginal + 1 == zEntity || zOriginal == zEntity) { zCollision = true; }


    //returns true if all 3 directions are true
    if (xCollision && yCollision && zCollision) { collision = true; }

    return collision;
}


int EntityControl::getYContainer() const
{
    return _yContainer;
}

int EntityControl::getXContainer() const
{
    return _xContainer;
}

int EntityControl::getZContainer() const
{
    return _xContainer;
}

EntityControl::~EntityControl()
{
}
```

It worked before, don't know exactly what has changed. I think everything is declared like it should but this has been bothering me for a while. Putting the classes in another project and running it from there didn't work either. Neither did changing around some variables / removing methods, but again, I might have missed something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolve header include circular dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-header-include-circular-dependencies)

Comment: You should produce a [mcve]. I am pretty sure almost all of your code is irrelevant.

Comment: Well it's kind of difficult to know what to post when you don't even know why the error appears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that when you include *EntityControl.h* you have also included *Fish.h* which refers to `Fish` defined in *Fish.h*. However *EntityControl.h* refers to *Fish.h* which won't get included because of the `pragma once` directive. If you remove `pragma once` then you'd get an infinite loop because of circular dependency.

To solve the problem of circular dependencies use forward declarations.
Remove `#include "EntityControl.h"` from *Fish.h* and write `class EntityControl;` instead.

You may also remove `#include "Fish.h";` from *EntityControl.h* and write `class Fish;` in its stead.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, undeclared identifier on EntityControl